# How do I prevent curd from getting sour?

Tags: storage-method, yogurt

I usually take homemade curd in lunchbox to work. Since there is almost 4-5 hours gap between the lunch break and time when I get my lunch packed. I don't have refrigerator or any cool medium to store it at work.

Just because of that long gap, curd usually gets sourer and becomes almost hard to consume.

Is there any particular method so I can prevent curd from getting sour?

Comment: @Jefromi Aren't curd and yogurt two different things?

Comment: Yogurt is a broad category; there may be differences between typical curd and typical American yogurt, but yogurt the most reasonable umbrella term in English. And it doesn't seem worth trying to distinguish between the two in tags; most things about one apply to the other, and people are inconsistent about which they use.

Comment: There's a difference at all? I have lived in both India and the US, and have never noticed any difference between *curd* as it's termed in India, and plain *yogurt* as it's termed in the US. I make my own yogurt in the US following pretty much the same process as I did for curd in India, with the minor difference that the lower temperature in the US makes incubation necessary, whereas in India I could just leave it out on the countertop to set. Also, in Indian grocery stores in the US, tubs of yogurt are labeled "dahi" in various Indic scripts, which is the same term used for curd in India.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As you already said yourself, cooling it will be easiest. Either use a cooled lunchbox with an ice pack insert, or, if taking it out of the refrigerator at morning, carry it in a thermos flask.

Alternatively, you have to get it out underfermented and let it ferment properly during these 4-5 hours. If you are taking just-ready room temperature curd, you can instead start the curd later, or start with cooler milk, or use less starter. If you are taking it from the fridge, you can start putting the curd into the fridge before it's done, so it reactivates and finishes fermentation in your bag. In any case, you will need lots of experimentation until you have the process such that the curd is properly done by the time you eat. Also, a few degrees Celsius difference in your environment will make it necessary to tweak the parameters.

Theoretically, the third option to try would be to kill off the culture when the curd is done, by heating it. But too little heat and the culture will survive, while too much heat and you will end up with quark. So this is only used in industrial settings.

Comment: The efficiency of modern thermos-types of containers is pretty amazing.